# What is a good practice to get the correct return class with inheritance?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, polymorphism

I have different types of users, all of them inheriting from a parent class User:

```
class User(string username, string password){...}

class UserAdmin(string username, string password) extends User{
   ...
   // new methods
}

class User(string username, string password) extends User{
   ...
   // new methods
}
```

I have a method to login, but the thing is that if I login with the credentials of a UserAdmin I want to return a UserAdmin, same things for all the other child classes of User.

```
public User login(String userName, String password) {
    for (User user : usersList) {
        if (user.isCorrectLogin(userName, password)) {
            return user;
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Login failed !");
}
```

How can I do that? Should I have multiple login() methods for each types of Users? Or is there a different way to design the users to not have this issue in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

A single login method should be just fine for your use case, though what you should do is make sure the correct type of `User` is already in `usersList`. For example:

```
List<User> usersList = new ArrayList<>();
usersList.add(new User("steve", "some_secret_password"));
usersList.add(new UserAdmin("bob", "some_even_more_secret_password"));
```

That way, your existing `login` method will automatically return the correct type.

If you want to check if the returned value is of a specific type you can use the `instanceof` operator:

```
User user = login(username, password);
if (user instanceof UserAdmin) {
  // Do privileged action
}
```

There are several other ways to go about this, however. You could simply have each specific user type return a set of roles it has, that way you can avoid `instanceof` altogether:

```
// User
public Set<String> getRoles() {
  return Set.of("user");
}

// UserAdmin
public Set<String> getRoles() {
  return Set.of("user", "admin");
}
```

Then your logic could become:

```
User user = login(username, password);
if (user.getRoles().contains("admin")) {
  // Privileged action
}
```

Comment: Alright, but if I want to have those privileged actions inside my users classes how could I do that ?

Comment: After you do the `instanceof` check you can cast the reference to the proper type. `UserAdmin admin = (UserAdmin) user;`